# Unable to load actual image sizes on first run using javascript plugin (images are loading after refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html5-canvas

I am using a javascript plugin http://flipbit.co.uk/2009/03/jquery-image-annotation-plugin.html to annotate images. I am unable to load my images in the exact size on the first run but it works when i refresh the page. When i am trying to do window.onload inside the function in the below code it loads the images but annotations are removed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url.....

      success:function(data){

       //adding data to div 
      $("#imgID").append($("<img src="" id="" />"));

       //then calling this method
 function annotateAllImages(id) {
 $(window).load(function() {
    $("#"+id).annotateImage({
        getUrl: id+'/getAnnotationData',
        saveUrl: id+'/saveData',
        deleteUrl: id+'/deleteData',
        editable: true,
        useAjax: true,
                });
           });
        }
</script>
```

I tried doing  $(window).load(function() { for the complete script but still it's not working. The canvas creation and stuff are done inside the plugin that i am using. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add where you're calling annotateAllImages? I suspect that you're invoking it outside of the ajax call meaning it may run before all the images happen to load.

Comment: Hi kaminari I am adding two functions inside ajax call one to add images to div and after that i am calling a function inside the ajax call like the one below and this invokes the annotate AllImages var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); annotateImageIds(imgs);

Comment: FYI this is the code http://ideone.com/z4L9gR

Comment: The below is how it looks on first run http://postimg.org/image/abz98exc9/ and when i refresh it looks like this http://postimg.org/image/5tf4xxde5/93ee1c8f/

Comment: After a preliminary glance at your code, the library and your images, I've noticed that you're not using $(window).load. The library mentions not using $(document).ready and instead $(window).load. Have you tried using $(window).load to wrap all your relevant script not just what is in the annotateAllImages function? That is to say, replace your $(document).ready with $(window).load.

Comment: Yes i did that inspite of doint $(window).load(function() { ... followed by ajax calls and adding images to div and annotations... }); Still it behaves the same.

Comment: Ok, getting closer then, sorry for the multitude of comments, debugging :) Is your ajax call requesting the images in question? I couldn't tell for sure given the endpoint. I'm imagining now that if that's the case that you should bind your image manipulations to the individual image load events. This would explain why on refresh (once these image resources have been cached) it appears to work since they are already loaded.

Comment: My Ajax calls an API which gives me the image names from my file system. I parse json and get the image paths and do this $("#imgID").append($("<img src=" ... How to do the binding of images can you show an example. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem. I understand now. You should be able to do it via the selectors that you have: 

$('#' + id).load(function() { $(this).annotateImage( ... ) }); 

I'm referencing the very last example on jQuery load http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: That works like a Charm. Thank you verymuch kaminari. You can comment below i will tick it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be solved by applying all image edits in the `$.load` function for each image individually.

This is because the source tags of each element are set dynamically after an ajax call thus requiring further time for each image asynchronously.

For reference the snippet looks something like this:

```
function annotateAllImages(id) {
    $("#"+id).load(function(){
        $(this).annotateImage({
            getUrl: id+'/getAnnotationData',
            saveUrl: id+'/saveData',
            deleteUrl: id+'/deleteData',
            editable: true,
            useAjax: true,
        });
    });
}
```